# Is it possible to change from spouse residence permit to a work permit visa in Germany?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, resident-permit

At the moment, I am on a research visa and my husband joined me at the beginning of the year on a family dependent visa. He found a job very soon (he is in the IT sector) as he is entitled to work while on a spouse dependent visa. My project is ending at the end of the year as well as my visa.

Is there the possibility of us changing the residence types while within Germany,  my husband from dependent to his own work permit visa, and me from research to spouse dependent visa? Just to emphasize that he has an unlimited contract and the company wants to keep him.

Comment: Just go ask the local Bürgeramt? They might walk you through what need to be done in your specific case.

Comment: Normally I already did that. But in some places die Ausländerbehörde are not so helpful...they said come on your appointment for visa prolongation and you will see if this is possible. This is so stupid since now three months I will not know anything until I go to the appointment....hence my question here if anybody had a similar situation?

Comment: Which residence permit (paragraphs) do you have now?

Answer (score 1):

My answer may come too late, but still relevant for the people in the similar situation. In general such changes should be possible, but depends on current residence permit and how long one have been in Germany with that residence permit.

There is a [nice overview of possible changes of the purpose of residence](https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/EN/Publikationen/EMN/Studien/wp67-emn-wechsel-aufenthaltstiteln-aufenthaltszwecken.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) provided by Federal Office for Migration and Refugees (Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge - BAMF). Please see the tables on pages 26 and 27 there, which exactly describe all such possibilities. It is also available [in German](https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/DE/Publikationen/EMN/Studien/wp67-emn-wechsel-aufenthaltstiteln-aufenthaltszwecken.pdf?__blob=publicationFile).

The one should take into account that the law behind this document might be a subject of change after some time.

P.S. I'm not a lawyer.